# Weird symptoms from the clutch

Tags: clutch, vauxhall, insignia

I drive Vauxhall Insignia diesel, 2.0. Never had any problems with a clutch, and yesterday it developed 3 faults!

1. There is a grinding noise when the clutch pedal is pressed, not very loud. But definitely noticeable.
2. Car vibrates badly when the clutch is about to engage. But this comes and goes as you drive.
3. Clutch did not properly engage two times. I released the pedal completely but it took 1-2 seconds for the car to actually move.

Should I look into replacing clutch, DMF or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

It definitely sounds like an issue with the clutch and / or dual mass flywheel.  The noise you described could be attributed to the release bearing which is part of the clutch kit.  All of the other symptoms point to an issue with the dual mass flywheel.

Comment: Agree, I used to own a 2.0 CDTI Insignia and i heard from garage techs that there are common issues with the DMF.

Comment: Has there ever been a DMF from any manufacturer that didn't have issues? Sounds like a part of the "Full Employment for Mechanics Act". They work great until they don't.

Comment: A DMF is a consumable item designed to protect the gearbox.